# Web Audio Api high gain values make noisy crackle sound (bad sound quality)

Tags: web-audio-api

My Goal is it to control the volume every frame based on the input sound volume.
Now I have the problem that the higher the gain value (GainNode) the worse the sound quality, maybe it is something like a sound overload. Gain value <1 is no problem but >1 its getting bad. Is there any other way than changing the gain value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(84, 84, 84);">
   <button onclick="sound()" style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 500px; scale: 5;" id="btn">
      <audio src="/forever.mp3"></audio>
      Forever Sound
   </button>
   
   <script>
      const audioElement = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
      const audioContext = new AudioContext();
      const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
      const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
      //analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
      analyser.fftSize = 1024;
      const gain = audioContext.createGain();
      source.connect(analyser).connect(gain).connect(audioContext.destination);
      
      




      const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
      btns.forEach(btn => {
         btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
         audioContext.resume();
      });
      });


      var soundclicked = false;
      function sound() {
         if (!soundclicked){
            audioElement.play();
            soundclicked = true;
            //AudioContext.resume().then(() => {
            //   console.log('Playback resumed successfully');
            //});
            
         }
         else{
            audioElement.pause();
            soundclicked = false;
         }
      }

      //var timer = setInterval(interval,500)
      function interval(){
         console.log(dataArray.length);
      }




      const wantedVolume = 50;

      function step() {
         var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
         analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
         var average = getAverageVolume(array);
         if (average > 0){
            var volumeratio = (wantedVolume/average); // HERE
            gain.gain.value = volumeratio;            // IS THE PROBLEM I think
            //gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(volumeratio,audioContext.currentTime +0.03)
         }
   
         console.log('VOLUME:' + average,volumeratio,gain.gain.value); 
         window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
   
      function getAverageVolume(array) {
         var values = 0;
         var average;
   
         var length = array.length;
   
          // get all the frequency amplitudes
         for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values += array[i];
         }
      
         average = values / length;
         return average;
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
   

   </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

I tried linearRampToValueAtTime() but it doesnt make sense because every frame the value changes.
I also lowered the gain values but >1 is always a problem and gain values like 20 are horrible but it should be possible in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to insert a DynamicsCompressorNode. 1/60th of a second gap between screen refreshes is long enough for the source volume to rise and overload the output. The value of each individual sample from your input source (as they arrive at 48,000 times a second or whatever) multiplied by your gain value must never exceed 1 in order to avoid crackle (nor go below -1). The DynamicsCompressorNode will correct the overshoot.

(That is, when routing the output of your GainNode to the audio out. Obviously, for pitch modulation and stuff then values can exceed plus or minus 1.)